# Filter from Pipeline separated string in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST library in .NET for query. I have a mapped a property as CurrentProductStatus(a string). In a document sample record for CurrentProductStatus is like this :
"OldStatus|Scanned: [PURCHASE] Recieved|0|#f6f6f6"

So i have to filter the result with the second pipeline separated string(ex: "Scanned: [PURCHASE] Recieved"). I have tried with Standard Analyzer. Didnt work for me.

```
 QueryContainer query = null;
 query &= Query<SearchProduct>.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.CurrentProductStatus).Query(searchParameters.ProductStatus).Analyzer("standard"));
```

This is part of my code, this is where i querying.

Any idea to do the searching and filtering ??

Answer (score 0):

[Using Ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with [a pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ingest-node-a-clients-perspective) looks like it may be a good fit here, to parse separate fields out of the `CurrentProductStatus` field, and add them to the document that is indexed. You can then query on these fields.

The alternative is to define an analyzer that tokenizes the input in a way conducive to your use case. For example, the Standard Analyzer is going to tokenize in the following way

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["OldStatus|Scanned: [PURCHASE] Recieved|0|#f6f6f6"]
}

---

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "oldstatus",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scanned",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "purchase",
      "start_offset": 20,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "recieved",
      "start_offset": 30,
      "end_offset": 38,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "0",
      "start_offset": 39,
      "end_offset": 40,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "f6f6f6",
      "start_offset": 42,
      "end_offset": 48,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

With the Standard Analyzer applied at query time to `Scanned: [PURCHASE] Recieved`,

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["Scanned: [PURCHASE] Recieved"]
}

----

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "scanned",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "purchase",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "recieved",
      "start_offset": 20,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Three tokens will match for a `match` query.